# why go-ethereum client auto send all balance to outer

Tags: go-ethereum

**My repotest net go-ethereum client auto send all banlance to outer address?**

You can click [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xad03df4327299da58849c27e867ca76b53836b485c5179c6b2189637efa7f590).

Comment: Did you enable rpc and unlock your account?

Comment: yes, My command is the followed:                                                                           build/bin/geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --cache=1024 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --datadir "./data" console 2>>eth.log

Comment: Then if you unlock your account; anyone can send out all your balance; never unlock your account or enable rpc for all like you did

Answer (score 0):

If you enable rpc api for public like this `build/bin/geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --cache=1024 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --datadir "./data" console 2>>eth.log` and you unlock your account; then everyone can call function to send out all your balance.

Actually, there're many spyware to sweep out all the network to do this then you will be quickly become a victim. So never open your end-point to public and never never unlock your account also.